# Disabling click events on 'disabled' pagination in Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I'm trying to disable click events on 'disabled' pagination buttons in Datatables.

I've been trying to do so like with this code

```
$('.dataTables_paginate span.ui-state-disabled').click(function(){return false;});
```

But that only works on the worded navigation (i.e., Next, Previous, First, Last) and not the numbering. I've tried targeting it a dozen different ways, to no avail. Is there something in the datatables API that I'm missing, or does anyone out there have another idea how to disable this? The disable class is applied dynamically through datatables.

If you have a minute, please help -- this is driving me crazy!

Comment: they should be disabled by default and unclickable unless there's another page it can navigate to.. Can you make an example on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 3):

Too late to participate but for the others I solve this issue using CSS only

```
a.paginate_button.current {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the datatable api probably have a click listener for paginations buttons and they will be executed before yours scripts.

BUT: if your intention is to stop the default event of the click, try that:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate span.ui-state-disabled').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to override these? preventDefault(), stopPropagation() and the like don't seem to work.

Comment: If you have access to the datatable scripts you can change the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.preventDefault();` to your click function.